# How to create an invincibility powerup on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

How to create an invincibility powerup on unity?

I'm new to Unity and I'm making a runner type game in which I want to add a powerup that when the player picks it up, it makes them invincible for a few seconds so they can  trespass obstacles and not die.

Right now this is what I have on my powerup script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float duracion=5f;
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if(other.CompareTag("Player")){
            StartCoroutine(Pickup(other));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Pickup(Collider player){
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Physics.IgnoreCollision(FindObjectsOfType<Collider>());
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duracion);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to refer to the player in this case so the effect applies on them and honestly I'm not sure if `Physics.IgnoreCollision` is correct. Does anyone know how I can make the player not trigger collisions when touching an obstacle? All the obstacle objects have the `isTrigger` box checked and are tagged as obstacles. I appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision` instead.

It requires a little setup and is very similar to your solution, you're close!

Create a new Layer for your obstacles. For example, "Obstacle," and add it to the obstacle prefab, so that every instantiated obstacle GameObject has the correct layer name.

Then, you can additionally create a layer for your player. For example, "Player," and add it to the Player or Character GameObject.

Don't forget that after you create layers, you have to add them to GameObjects manually.

We will refactor the existing code a bit to handle the invincibility in the Player script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PowerUp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")){
            var player = other.GetComponent<Player>();
            
            if (player) {
                player.TriggerInvincibility();
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Player script, you can either store layers in variables or do it inline. I will cache them in the `playerLayer` and `obstacleLayer` variables because you might be needing them repeatedly.

```cs
// ...

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int playerLayer;
    private int obstacleLayer;

    private float invincibilityDuration = 1f;
    
    private void Start() {
        // ... your code

        playerLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player");
        obstacleLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Obstacle");
    }

    public void TriggerInvincibility() {
        StartCoroutine(InvincibilityRoutine());
    }

    private IEnumerator InvincibilityRoutine() {
        Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLayer, obstacleLayer);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(invincibilityDuration);
        Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLayer, obstacleLayer, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it appears to work but now I have another problem and is that when the player collects the powerup he falls through the ground. I think it has to do with it being a RigidBody. Is there a way to diable collision only with objects tagged as obstacle?

Comment: Right. Thanks for specifying. I've updated the answer with a more appropriate method.